# Orientation of a geometric simplex - ordering of its vertices

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am studying simplicial homology and I am a bit confused about the definition of an *orientation* of a (finite) geometric simplex.

The definition says that two orderings of a simplex are equivalent if they differ by an even permutation, and so we get two equivalence classes - two orientations.

My question is, what is an *ordering* of a simplex? Is it just a permutation of the vertices or does it have to satisfy some other rules? If it's defined to be a permutation of vertices, then we draw paths between vertices indicated by the permutation of vertices (I am thinking geometrically), then my lines might cross each other. Is it that this will not happen because vertices of a simplex are in general position?

Thank you!

Comment: The orientation of a simplex is the parity of the order in which you list the vertices. That's a combinatorial feature, which has nothing to do with drawing paths or with lines crossing.

Comment: I assume you talk about an abstract simplex? The ordering means concrete indexation of vertices. Or equivalently turning it into an ordered sequence. I'm not sure why would you draw lines and why them crossing or not matters?

Comment: @frekish I am talking about geometric simplex, not the abstract one. I am just to visualizing an ordering by drawing it on the simplex, so I kinda care about whether a specific ordering might lead to paths crossing.

Comment: @frekish May I wonder what does it mean for two orderings (permutations) to differ by an even permutation?

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you. @freakish

Comment: Your finite collection of vertices live in $\mathbb R^n$. You have two different orderings of them, listed from left to right.  So collect the associated coordinate vectors and adjoin them from left to right to get matrices $V_1$ and $V_2$.  One ordering is a permutation of the other so $V_1 = V_2 P$ for some permutation matrix $P$.  They are equivalent *iff* $\det\big(P\big) =1$.

Comment: As far as lines crossing: that can't happen. An $n$-simplex always includes each edge connecting any pair of its vertices, so changing the order of the vertices will not add or remove or change which edges are present. It cannot cause edges to suddenly cross. (Think of a triangle or a tetrahedron.)

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with drawing lines and them crossing or not.

We consider the set of vertices $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\}$. This set can be ordered, meaning arranged into a sequence $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$. I use round brackets now to emphasise that the order matters. So if we take another sequence $u=(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ from our set of vertices, then there is a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ such that

$$u_i=w_{\sigma(i)}$$

for all $i\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

Now two such sequences $w$ and $u$ differ by an even permutation means that $\sigma$ is [even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation).

For example if $w=(a,b,c)$ and $u=(b,c,a)$ then they differ by an even permutation. And so in this context these are similar. But $w=(a,b,c)$ and $u=(a,c,b)$ do not differ by an even permutation, and these are not similar.

Now if we make a relationship out of it, it turns out that on a given simplex there are only two such possible choices, up to even permutation. And this is orientation. It is quite simple to visualize it in one-dimensional case, we have two orientations here: $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$. In some sense the first one represents "left to right" while the second one "right to left". In two-dimensional case we also have only two orientations (like in any dimension): one of them represents "clockwise" and the other one "counterclockwise".